# How to read the data from xlsx file when file is already open in C#

Tags: c#, wpf

When I read the data from .xlsx file(ope in microsft excel) it genrates the error "File is used in another process". For data reading, I am using **File.ReadAllBytes(*strPath*)** Function.

So is there is any solution/code, which can remove this type of error so that I can succesfully read the data.

Comment: Do you need Excel to have the file opened while you're reading it? If not, can you close Excel?

Comment: @Leon I am using FileSystemWatcherClass and I want to take the data from file when it press ctrl+s event on xlsx file. So for that it is mandatory file should be open.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
using (FileStream fs = File.Open(filepath,FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read,FileShare.ReadWrite))
{
 // do you stuf
}
```